# Connecting to MySQL database error in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar

I have a java code and I am connecting to the mysql database with the following connection string.

```
 String userName = "admin";
 String password = "pass";
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://<my IP>/dbase"; //not localhost
 Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
```

When I make a JAR (Runnable JAR through eclipse), and take it to another machine in the same network I get an error

```
Access denied for user 'admin'@'<another machine IP' (using password: YES) //not localhost
```

The IP magically changed to another machine IP when I take the JAR to another machine. admin user has all privileges possible.

Whats wrong? Please help !!

Comment: You are trying to access the database from the other machine ip.  Therefore the error is correct.  Is your MySQL server configured to allow access from that IP?

Comment: Have you hardcoded your IP there?

Comment: why is that `root` is on the error message where in fact userName = `admin`? even if it changes its IP, the username will still be `admin` not `root`.

Comment: @johntotetwoo - the default root user for MySQL is `admin`

Comment: @thinksteep yes I have hardcoded the IP in my program. The IP changes in the other machine

Comment: @BrianRoach I believe you are incorrect.  Source: Mysql Docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: Then he's using the user `root` in his actual code - it's been a while since I've used MySQL. Either way, the MySQL server is telling him he can't connect from that machine as that user.

Comment: Sorry guys, I first used admin in my code and then used root in my code. The error was the same. I accidently copied the code with "admin" and error with "root". I have edited my post.. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP address listed in the error message is *the IP address of the machine your program is running on*. It's telling you that you're not allowed to connect to MySQL *from* that IP address as `root`

You will need to talk to the person who configures/administers your MySQL database. More than likely this is an intentional security measure.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am sure this is the problem. I'll consult my DBA tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should run the below command.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'admin'%'@' identified by 'pass';
flush privilges;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think There is no problem with your Java code. Also try to connect the mysql server from command prompt

```
mysql -u root -h <ip address> -p
```

If you got the same error then the possible reason would be
1. In correct password
2. Permission is denied to access via network

You can give permission using below command

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* to root@'ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```